# How to get variable name of object inside class?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have class `A` which stores ref to object `B` in `BObject` variable.

```
public class A
{
    public B BObject;
}
```

I want to get `BObject` ( name of variable ) in `B` class constructor.

Is there any way to do this ?

Purpose of doing it: I want to create `ODBCFramework` and I want to get Table Name based on Variable Name. ( Like in EntityFramework Context )

**Update:** I want to handle it in C#5.

Comment: When the constructor is called, there is no knowledge available about whether the resultant object will be stored in *any* named variable - or it may in fact be stored in *multiple* variables. Explain more about what problem you're trying to solve (hint: the *problem* exists at a higher level than "find the name of the variable where the object is going to be stored")

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Ok, I have `ODBCContext` class. I want to store there for example `ODBCSet<CustomerModel> AR_Customer = new ODBCSet<CustomerModel>();` And in my ODBCSet I want to get `AR_customer` ( as it is my table name) to query this table and fill my `DBSet`.

Comment: If this is meant to be in analogy of the `DbContext`/`DbSet` classes in EF, then you should be aware that the magic there happens within the `DbContext` object, reflecting over itself, rather than inside the `DbSet` constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever give me some points to solve my problem. And I tried this, and it works.

```
public class A
{
    public B BObject { get; set; }
    public A()
    {
        var BTypeProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(B));
        foreach (var prop in BTypeProperties)
        {
            prop.SetValue(this, new B(prop.Name));
        }
    }

}

public class B
{
    string _propName;
    public B(string propertyName)
    {
        _propName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

Also, to be clear in answer:
@Yuval Itzchakov suggested that in C#6 solution is:

```
var a = new A();
string bName = nameof(a.B);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use C#-6 [`nameof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx):

```
var a = new A();
string bName = nameof(a.B);
```

Note that generally attempting to relay on a run-time name of a property/field for table lookup seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Thank You, but I forget to say that I want handle it in C# 5.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do what you want.

You cannot find the name of whatever it is that is storing the reference to your object, that information is simply not available.

Basically, this:

```
var x = new BObject();
// from inside BObject, get the name "x"
```

is not possible. The fact that you have stored it in a field of another object changes nothing, it simply cannot be done.

You need to have a way to explicitly *tell* that object which table name it should use.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

```
var a = B.GetInfo().GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in a)
    string name = propertyInfo.Name
```

Comment: If I have 2 properties of type `B` how I will determinate which is currently created ?

Comment: Good point. My mistake, this won't solve your problem as it only gives you the name of declared properties. I think @Lasse has the correct answer.